# As a "target" handler toolbar button, the method of the controller?

Tags: extjs-mvc

**Hello!**

I want this handler "handler: onEventControler (???)" removed from view (it do not belong there)

For grid view  set dockedItems this  cod:

```
        this.dockedItems = [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'newstation'
        },{
            id: 'add-persone-btn',
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'add',
            text: 'Add',
            iconCls: 'icon-add',  
            handler: onEventControler(???)
        }, '-', {
            itemId: 'delete',
            text: 'Delete',
            iconCls: 'icon-delete',
            disabled: true,
            handler: function(){
                var selection = grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                if (selection) {
                    store.remove(selection);
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
```

I also tried to implement a **this.control**, but I could not ask for a button selectorQuery.

How do I properly respecting the architecture mvc extJs4?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this inside the controller of this view.

```
init: function () {
  this.control({
    'toolbar #add': {
      click: this.onAddStation
    }        
  });
}
```

Handler:

```
onAddStation: function(button, e, eOpts){
  //Handle
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an "action" config on your button.

```
action: 'addstation'
```

Then you could have:

```
init: function () {
  this.control({
    'button[action=addstation]': {
      click: me.onAddStation
    }        
  });
}
```

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button

Comment: The first case did not help!
Alternativyny option to work, probably because of the dynamic creation of the toolbar, ie do not know why the first option did not work ...

Comment: Try removing id and using just itemId or change `toolbar #add` to `#add-persone-btn`

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice your id.  Have you tried David's suggestion?  Do you require an 'id' for any reason?

Comment: Yeah, I used a lot of options ))
Don't want to work through the css "id" selector.

ps. example
init: function () {
  this.control({
    '#add-persone-btn': {
      click: this.onAddStation
    }        
  });
}

No effect

Comment: Did you make sure that your controller is actually "controlling" the view.  "itemId" is within the scope of the particular component.  Is the view you are trying to control in the views config of the controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is method "initComponent" for view gridd view:

```
initComponent: function () {
    this.plugins = [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing')];

    this.dockedItems = [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'add',
            text: 'Add',
            iconCls: 'icon-add',
            action: 'add-new-persone'
        }, '-', {
            itemId: 'delete',
            text: 'Delete',
            iconCls: 'icon-delete',
            action: 'delete-persone',
            disabled: true
        }, '-', {
            itemId: 'synch',
            text: 'Synchronization',
            iconCls: 'icon-synch',
            action: 'synch-persone'
        }]
    }];

    // paging bar on the bottom
    this.bbar = Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
        store: this.store,
        displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
        emptyMsg: "No topics to display",
        items:[]
    });

    this._initColumns();
    this._initFilter();
    this.callParent(arguments);
},
```